# Convert decimal value into words in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to convert decimal number into words in crystal report.
So I created a formula field

```
ProperCase( ToWords(Truncate(CDbl ({@AmountInDecimal})),0) )+" Only"
```

Eg: For `@AmountInDecimal =8031.29',
the result is the following : Eight thousand thirty one only

Only the integer part gets converted, decimal places are not getting converted.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currencyvar Original;

currencyvar deci;

Original:={@AmountInDecimal};

deci:= Original- Truncate(Original);

Original:= truncate(Original);

deci:= deci* 100;

if deci= 0 then 
'Rupees ' + ToWords (Original,0 ) + ' Only'

else

'Rupees ' + ToWords (Original,0) + ' And Paisa ' + ToWords(deci,0) + ' Only ';

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Truncate function.

```
ProperCase( ToWords(CDbl ({@AmountInDecimal})) )+" Only"
```

Result:

> Eight Thousand Thirty-One And 29 / 100 Only